# Can one read the Shanti Parva of the Mahabharata without reading the other Parvas of the Mahabharata?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata

Can a person read the Shanti Parva of the Mahabharata without consulting/reading the other Parvas behind it? Or in other words can somebody read the Shanti Parva without the context of the Mahabharata?

Comment: What makes you think you couldn't? There are probably parts you wouldn't understand, but it's not as though you'd be struck by lightning if you did.

Comment: @CDR I asked because I wanted to read it but I thought that you might need (like it's mandatory) to read the other Parvas to understand it. Well going from what you said I don't think I need to know the context to understand it.

Comment: It's certainly not mandatory. In terms of _understanding_ the context you may have a bit of a struggle, but you're not going to get any heavenly comeuppance, i.e., it's not forbidden by scripture.

Comment: @CDR thanks! I guess I will start reading it.